# Copy/Clone objects from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have relations as follows :

```
Customer has many Orders
Order has many Parts
```

What I'm trying to do is to assign orders/parts to another customer, but I want to keep the original customer/orders/parts relation. So I tried this (assuming `customer` is a Customer instance)

```
another_customer_id = 22
customer.orders.each do |order|
  ord = order.dup
  ord.customer_id = another_customer_id
  ord.save!
  order.parts.each do |part|
    prt = part.dup
    prt.order_id = ord.id
    prt.save!
  end
end
```

So I'm assuming once I do `customer_two.orders` I will get everything as in first customer, but strangely I don't. It seems the first customer has double the orders/parts.

How can I do this in a better way?

**update**

When I use `.dup` method the original customers orders are doubled in the database.
When I use `.clone` instead of `.dup` nothing happens, another customer still doesn't have orders from original customer

Comment: do you need to persistent into database, or just in memory?

Comment: Have you inspected `ord` after you change the `customer_id` (line 4) and after you save it?

Comment: What version of Rails is this?

Comment: @theIV it appears that ord has the same id after I save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have here looks reasonable to me if you are using Rails >= 3.1.  Before Rails 3.1 you need to use `clone` instead of `dup`.  However, here is another method that you can try:

```
another_customer_id = 22
customer.orders.each do |order|
  ord = Order.create(order.attributes.merge(:customer_id => another_customer_id))
  order.parts.each do |part|
    Part.create(part.attributes.merge(:order_id => ord.id))
  end
end
```